# inserting files in sql server

Tags: sql-server, file, ms-word, store

greetings!

I'm having some problems on a system that I'm giving support.
There's a scenario where users can upload their resumé to the database (MS SQL Server 2005) and it was decided that the application should store these documents in a table with a varbinary column. I Tried many examples found on the internet but I can't figure out why the application does not store bytes from a microsoft word document (.doc). If I try to store a more recent version (.docx or xlsx) or even a .txt, the functionality works perfectly.

I tried also store pdf files in that same column but didn't work too.
I guess it is something with document format, i don't know

Could you guys give some help. I'm desperate looking for one solution.

Here's the script that I created for my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[resumes](
    [id_professional] [int] NOT NULL,
[professional_name] [varchar](50)  NULL,
[file_type] [varchar](50) NULL,
[data] [varbinary](max)  NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_resumes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    id_professional] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And here's the code that I'm trying make it work:

```
foreach (string upload in Request.Files)
{
    //create byte array of size equal to file input stream
byte[] fileData = new byte[Request.Files[upload].InputStream.Length];
//add file input stream into byte array
Request.Files[upload].InputStream.Read(fileData, 0,
    Convert.ToInt32(Request.Files[upload].InputStream.Length));
//create system.data.linq object using byte array
System.Data.Linq.Binary binaryFile = new System.Data.Linq.Binary(fileData);

Resume objResume = new Resume()
objResume.data= binaryFile;

ResumeDAO.Save(objResume);
}
```

By the way, i 'm using linq to sql in this application.

Comment: Does it just not upload, or does it upload and mangle the file?

Comment: It inserts the record in the table, but when I look this record, the bytes column (varbinary) is empty. If try inserting files with docx or xlsx extensions (newer version of MS Office Word/ MS Office Excel), it inserts right in the database, with bytes column filled.

Comment: Any errors in the error log? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187109.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Single Line Insert any file into table.
And, a single dynamic procedure to write back to Hard disk...
May be You are looking for this ::

```
--FIRST CHANGE THE CONFIGURATION TO ACTIVATE THIS FEATURE
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures';
GO
---------------------------------------------------------

--HOW TO WRITE FILES TO DIRECTLY SQL SERVER FROM DISC
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTemp](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ImageType] [varchar] (10) NULL,
[ImageFile] [image] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Insert [tblTemp] (ImageFile) Select '.PDF',BulkColumn from Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\mak\A.PDF', Single_Blob) as tb
-----------------------------------------------------

--HOW TO WRITE FILE TO DISC FROM SQL SERVER
--WriteBinaryToDisc 'C:\NEWF\','MAK','.PDF','DOC_TABLE','DOC_ID','DOC_IMAGE','WHERE DOC_ID=''25'''
ALTER PROCEDURE WriteBinaryToDisc 
(
@Path VARCHAR(255),
@Filename VARCHAR(100),
@FileExt VARCHAR(4),
@TblName varchar(50),
@IDField VARCHAR(50),
@ImageField VARCHAR(50),
@WHERE VARCHAR(300)
    )
AS
set nocount on
EXEC ('
DECLARE @SOURCEPATH VARBINARY(MAX),
@DESTPATH VARCHAR(MAX),
@ObjectToken INT,
@image_ID BIGINT

DECLARE IMGPATH CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT '+@ImageField+','+@IDField+' from     '+@TblName+' '+@WHERE+' 
OPEN IMGPATH

FETCH NEXT FROM IMGPATH INTO @SOURCEPATH, @image_ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @DESTPATH = '''+@Path+'\'+@Filename+'''+ CAST(@image_ID AS     varchar)+'''+@FileExt+'''

EXEC sp_OACreate ''ADODB.Stream'', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, ''Type'', 1
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, ''Open''
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, ''Write'', NULL, @SOURCEPATH
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, ''SaveToFile'', NULL, @DESTPATH, 2
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, ''Close''
EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken

FETCH NEXT FROM IMGPATH INTO @SOURCEPATH, @image_ID
END

CLOSE IMGPATH
DEALLOCATE IMGPATH
')
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here what you have to do is, first upload the file to the server and Execute the statement above by modifying as your requirement. Im using image data type, which supports any file. So, store the extension so later when you again save it back to the hdd as file you can attach that extension again.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the issue stems from multi-byte encoding.

The "length" of a unicode character like ☃ is one, but the number of bytes is six.

Instead of

```
Convert.ToInt32(Request.Files[upload].InputStream.Length)
```

use

```
Request.Files[upload].ContentLength
```

Comment: I changed as you suggested me but it still not working.
The action result works without errors but when I look for the record that I i've just insert, the column which should have keep those bytes is empty. I guess it is something about document format. I can even insert txt files, image files (png, jpg, etc), but word files (doc) just doesn't work.